# Can I see the version of a company app?

Tags: apps

Our company deploys apps outside Microsoft Store, [using enterprise certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx). Can I somewhere see the version of such installed app?

I can't use the Store app since company apps are not listed there.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to know the version of a company app?

Comment: @NeilTurner When an end user has a problem with the app, technical support wants to know if the user runs the latest version.

Comment: I'd speak nicely to the developers, and get them to expose that information *somewhere* (even if it is just on the splash screen) within the app

Comment: Typically if an app is pushed to the phone, it should automatically be the latest version - but the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless its published in the app or in your company store app, unfortunately there is no way to do so for an end user.

Comment: That's bad, Microsoft!

Comment: How is that bad :). Microsoft has given Organizations a flexibility to showcase and restrict the apps as they want it.